# Google Tag Manager not working on link clicks

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am facing a weird issue in Google Tag Manager as i am not able to track links with below markup

```
<a onclick="javascript:some_method(event, url, 'PARAM')">Test</a>
```

Wherever, in my code i get this kind of markup, link tracking is not working.

Is there anything special i need to do track links with `javascript:` notation?

> Trigger Looks like as below:

[image]

> Tag looks like as below:

[image]

**Any assistance please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with trigger condition. `Click Classes` - `matches CSS selector` - `.last-td a` will not work

Because `Click Classes` variable contains the **string** value of `class` attribute your DOM element.

**You have two different ways to solve your problem:**

1) You need to add some class to your `a` link. For example: `<a onclick="javascript:some_method(event, url, 'PARAM')" class="this-is-my-last-td-link">Test</a>`

Then this condition will work: `Click Classes` - `equals` - `this-is-my-last-td-link`

2) You can change your condition to `Click Element` - `matches CSS selector` -
`.last-td a` without changing your markup

**UPDATE**

Based on discussion in chat. Your function has `e.stopPropagation()` inside. You need to change it with `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: I tried it with click element. But no results even then

Comment: Then you also need to change type to ` Click - Just Links`. And once you did your changes, please clear cache in your browser and try again

Comment: Or maybe your onclick function stops event propagation?

Comment: It might me, then @Gags can you please check your function. If it has `return false;` then you need to replace it with `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is your event name

Comment: Yes.. In code, it has return false.. is there any other way to do it without changing in code

Comment: So what i have tried is that `<a onclick="javascript:some_method(event, url, 'PARAM');event.preventDefault()" class="this-is-my-last-td-link">Test</a>` .. but still not working

Comment: Is it working, if you will remove ` onclick="javascript:some_method(event, url, 'PARAM');event.preventDefault()"` from markup

Comment: Can you send the code of your function `javascript:some_method`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152422/discussion-between-gags-and-victor-leontyev).

Comment: @VictorLeontyev, Removing stopPropagation resulted into some other issues. :( ... and i tried `dataLayer.push({'eventLabel': 'Test'})` .. but i am not getting datalayer event in Realtime events? any idea

Comment: `dataLayer.push` is sending event to GTM. Then you need to configure GTM to send event to GA